# How can I test functions that have multiple returns?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm currently learning java and I am making an e commerce website. I am currently in the process of writing some tests. My question is that one of my mappings in my controller returns a different page based on the length of a list called results. It's a search item function, if the item doesn't exist it takes you back to the search item page, if there is one item with that name it takes you to a different page and if there is multiple instances of this item it returns you to a third page. The mapping is below.

```
@RequestMapping("/findItemByName")
    public String processFindForm(Item item, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
        // allow parameterless GET request for /products to return all records
        if (item.getItemName() == null) {
            item.setItemName(""); // empty string signifies broadest possible search
        }

        // find products by name
        List<Item> results = itemRepo.findByItemName(item.getItemName());
        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            // no products found
            result.rejectValue("name", "notFound", "not found");
            return "finditem";
        } else if (results.size() == 1) {
            // 1 product found
            item = results.iterator().next();
            model.put("item", item);
            return "showitem";
        } else {
            // multiple products found
            model.put("items", results);
            return "showitems";
        }

    }
```

No matter what I seem to do I can only get the function to return "finditem" whilst testing. I have this as my code so far in my class for testing.

```
@Mock
    Model model;
    @Mock
    Item item;
    @Mock
    Item item2;
    @Mock
    ItemRepository itemRepo;
    @Mock
    Map<String,Object> mockMap;
    @Mock
    BindingResult mockResult;
    @Mock
    List<Item> results;
    
    @InjectMocks

@Test
    public void testFindByItemNameReturnsFindItemWhenListLengthOne() {
        
        results.add(item);
        String expectedValue = "showitem";
        String actualValue = itemController.processFindForm(item, mockResult, mockMap);
        
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testFindByItemNameReturnsFindItemWhenListLengthTwo() {
        List<Item> results = new ArrayList<>();
        
        results.add(item2);
        results.add(item2);
        System.out.print(results.size());
        String expectedValue = "showitems";
        String actualValue = itemController.processFindForm(item, mockResult, mockMap);
        
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
```

How do I 'inject' (if that is the correct word) result into the function to change my actualValue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application?

Comment: @JanSchmitz Yes it is, apologies I should have stated that in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your `ItemController` in isolation I would suggest to mock away it's dependency to the `ItemRepositoy`.
How you do this depends on wether you want to write an integration or unit test.

Personally I prefer to test controller with integration tests.
Spring Boot offers the `@WebMvcTest` Annotation which disabled the full-auto configuration in your tests and instead configures only the components that are needed for your web layer.

Your tests would look something like this:

```
@WebMvcTest
class ItemControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void cleverTestName() throws Exception {
        // mock behaviour of itemRepository
        doReturn(Collections.emptyList()).when(itemRepository).findByItemName(anyString());

        //make request to the controller and check results
        mockMvc.perform(...)
                .andExpect(...);
    }
}
```

With this setup you can write the tests to check your responses.
For more Information on `@WebMvcTest` I would suggest [one of my own Blogpost](https://jschmitz.dev/2021/04/14/how_to_test_the_web_layer_of_your_spring_boot_application_with_webmvctest/) about the topic :)

Comment: I'll give it a proper read through now and see if I can get it to stick. I've only done JAVA for a few weeks so a lot of stuff in the blog is new but I'll try to wrap my head around it and apply it. Thanks!